# How to extract subtree of the javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, parsing, graphql

I have large JSON object returned by my nodejs API server. I want to give users ability to query subset of fields similar to GraphQL but without schema. Object that is returned by API have set of standard fields but also set of any  custom fields that users can add to its "custom" property. I looked at GraphQL and as far as i understand it requires descriptor that defines all fields by which you can query. Unfortunately it will not work since "custom" field can have anything. I want for user to send query along with GET request that escribes what fields i want include and what i want to exclude. For example if object has:

```
{
  user: {
    age: 25,
    weight: 170,
    name: "Joe"
  },
  book: {
    title: "Dune",
    description: "Space opera",
    localtion: {
      planet: "Arakis",
      population: 100000,
    },
    heroes: [
      {
        name: "Duke",
        age: 43
      },
      {
        name: "Paul",
        age: 16
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now if I want everything under user name and book planet name I would send something like:

```
{'user.name': true, 'book.location.planet': true}
```

But if I want everything under book except heroes I would send:

```
{'book': true, 'book.heroes': false}
```

Anyone knows library that have something close to it?

Edit:
Ideally it should be query array elements:

```
{'book.heroes[0]': true} // extract first element
{'book.heroes[:last].name': true} // extract only name for the last element
{'book.heroes.name': true} // extract only names for all elements
```

Comment: You can still use GraphQL and just not validate the query against a schema

Comment: Could you refer to an example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach

```js
const data={user:{age:25,weight:170,name:"Joe"},book:{title:"Dune",description:"Space opera",location:{planet:"Arakis",population:100000},heroes:[{name:"Duke",age:43},{name:"Paul",age:16},]}};


const extractData = (data, filters) => {
    const [pathsToInclude, pathsToExclude] = Object.keys(filters).reduce(
        (acc, keyPath) => {
            acc[filters[keyPath] ? 0 : 1].push(keyPath.split("."));
            return acc;
        },
        [[], []]
    );

    const result = pathsToInclude.length ? {} : { ...data };

    pathsToInclude.forEach((path) => {
        let current = path.shift();
        let obj = result;
        let dataObj = data;

        while (current && obj) {
            if (!path.length) {
                obj[current] = dataObj?.[current];
            } else {
                obj[current] ??= {};
                dataObj = dataObj[current];
            }
            obj = obj[current];
            current = path.shift();
        }
    });

    pathsToExclude.forEach((path) => {
        const keyToDelete = path.pop();

        let current = path.shift();
        let obj = result;

        while (obj[current]) {
            obj = obj[current];
            current = path.shift();
        }

        if (obj) {
            delete obj[keyToDelete];
        }
    });

    return result;
};

console.log(extractData(data, {"user.name": true,"book.location.planet": true}));

// Also works if you just want to return everything except some values
console.log(extractData(data, {"book.location": false}));
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Would be nice to find library that allows more advanced queries like array filtering by element index or field but if nothing like that exists then this is solid for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below logic.

```js
let obj = {
  user: {
    age: 25,
    weight: 170,
    name: "Joe"
  },
  book: {
    title: "Dune",
    description: "Space opera",
    location: {
      planet: "Arakis",
      population: 100000,
    },
    heroes: [
      {
        name: "Duke",
        age: 43
      },
      {
        name: "Paul",
        age: 16
      }
    ]
  }
}
let fields1 = {'book': true, 'book.heroes': false}
let fields2 = {'user.name': true, 'book.location.planet': true}



function queryObject(obj, fields) {
  let newObj = {}
  Object.keys(fields).forEach(field => {
    const arr = field.split('.');
    if(fields[field]) {
      let partialObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
      let addTo = newObj;
      for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(i === arr.length-1) {
          addTo[arr[i]] = partialObj[arr[i]]
        } else {
            if(i==0) {
            newObj[arr[i]] = {}
           } else {
            addTo[arr[i]] = {}
           } 
          addTo = addTo[arr[i]]
          partialObj = partialObj[arr[i]]
        }
      }
    } else {
      let partialObj = newObj
      for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(i === arr.length-1) {
          delete partialObj[arr[i]]
        } else {
          partialObj = partialObj[arr[i]]
        }
      }
    }
  })
  return newObj;
}

console.log(queryObject(obj, fields1))
console.log(queryObject(obj, fields2))
```